# Python: How to print the last value of a range list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code in Python:

```
import datetime
import re
import pymongo
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(d, d1):
    for n in range(int ((d1 - d).days)):
        yield d + timedelta(n)

#conect to db
uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
database = client['db']
collection = database['currency']


d = input('Insert beginning date (yyyy-mm-dd): ')
d1 = input('Insert end date (yyyy-mm-dd): ')

#search db
item = collection.find_one({"date" : d})
item1 = collection.find_one({"date" : d1})
datas = item['date']
datas1 = item1['date']

#convert string to object
dataObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(datas, "%Y-%m-%d")
dataObject1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(datas1, "%Y-%m-%d")


#range
mylist = []
for single_date in daterange(dataObject, dataObject1):
    mylist.append(single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    print(single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
print(mylist)
item = collection.find_one({"date" : mylist[0]})
print(item)
```

If a user inserts a beginning date like 2018-05-07 and an end date like 2018-05-11 it will print:

```
2018-05-07
2018-05-08
2018-05-09
2018-05-10
```

In this case it will only print until the 10th day, how should I do to print also the end date (2018-05-11)?

Comment: ...change `range(int ((d1 - d).days))` to `range(int ((d1 - d).days) + 1)`?

Comment: `range` is non-inclusive on the "max" value, meaning `range(10)` won't actually include `10`. If you want the value to be included, you have to add `1` to your range-max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many solutions to your question, however, I believe the easiest would be to adjust the `daterange(d, d1)` function, by simply adding 1 to the `range(int ((d1 - d).days))`.

```
def daterange(d, d1):
    for n in range(int ((d1 - d).days) + 1):
        yield d + timedelta(n)
```

The reason for this is that, as per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range), `range(stop)` does not output the stop value, but only the values 'before' it.